# Removed Footer from Layout of title page, remains as part of the layout

Tags: beamer, header-footer, titles

I want the footline not to be portrayed in the title page.

With this:

```
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{comein}{%
  \ifnum \insertframenumber=1
  \else
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth,ht=0.5cm]{white}
        \usebeamerfont{footline}\comein@footline
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \fi
}
```

The foot line remains empty/blank, but still is part of the page layout.

In pictures:

If I don't define a foot line at all the title page looks like this:

[image]

But if I do define a foot line it looks like this:

[image]

Anyone who can help me out to remove the foot line completely from the title page or could provide me with the needed changes to the definition of the title page to get the same title page with a foot line defined?

Definition of the title page:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{comein}{%
   \vspace{-1.2ex}
   \makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\rand\relax}
   \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,
        width=\textwidth,
        height=\textheight * 2 / 3 - \rand,
        arc=0mm,
        boxrule=0mm,
        /tcb/size=minimal,
        watermark graphics=graphics/title.jpg, watermark stretch=1]%
        \vspace{2.0cm}
        \hfill
    \hfill \pgfuseimage{comein_logo_titelseite}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2,raster force size=false,raster column skip=0cm]
      \begin{tcolorbox}[
        width=.8\textwidth,
        height=\textheight * 1 / 3 - \rand,
        /tcb/size=small,
        arc=0mm,
        boxrule=0mm,
        colback=col1]%
            \vspace{0.1cm}
      \begin{spacing}{0.8}
        \parbox{0.96\textwidth}{\usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle}\newline
      \end{spacing}
      \vspace{1ex}
      \usebeamerfont{topic}\usebeamercolor[fg]{topic}\inserttopic \newline
      \vfill
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor    \usebeamerfont{square}$\text{ }\blacksquare$       \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate%
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        width=.2\textwidth,
        height=\textheight * 1 / 3 - \rand,
        /tcb/size=small,
        arc=0mm,
        boxrule=0mm,
        colback=white]%
        \begin{center}
         \pgfuseimage{bmbf_logo}\\         
         \pgfuseimage{chair_logo}\\
         \insertlicense
        \end{center}
     \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcbraster}
     \end{minipage}%
  }%
    \begin{textblock*}{0.5\textwidth}[0,0](\doppelrand, \doppelrand)
      \ifx\insertslidesurl\empty
      \else
      \usebeamercolor[white]{frametitle}
      \textcolor{white}{\qrcode[height=1cm]{\insertslidesurl}}
      \fi
    \end{textblock*}
  }
```

Thank you in advance!
Tristan

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `plain` frame option for your title frame.

To make sure this happens automatically from within  your theme, you could use something like

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth,ht=0.5cm]{white}
        \usebeamerfont{footline}footline
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@navigation@titlepage{%
  \@nameuse{ps@empty}
}
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\thispagestyle{navigation@titlepage}}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```